# How to add shaded curve line in the middle of two html tables using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have created a function that compare row items of two html tables. Comparison function is successful, however I need to point out where the changes occur by adding a shaded curve line in the middle of tables, and it needs to be dynamic.

Is it possible with web application? Currently I am using html table in the middle, but I don't know how to add the curve line.

Here is the screenshot of what I did:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve - the shaded curve line in the middle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create an SVG vector drawing and set it as the CSS `background-image: url(...);` property of your HTML element with CSS `background-size: 100% 100%;`

```css
.curve-left-right-top {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'><g><path d='m0,0l100,0c-50,0 -50,100 -100,100' stroke-width='1.5' stroke='black' fill='gray' /></g></svg>");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.curve-left-right-bottom {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'><g><path d='m0,100l100,0c-50,0 -50,-100 -100,-100' stroke-width='1.5' stroke='black' fill='gray' /></g></svg>");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.curve-right-left-top {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'><g><path d='m100,100l-100,0c50,0 50,-100 100,-100' stroke-width='1.5' stroke='black' fill='gray' /></g></svg>");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.curve-right-left-bottom {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'><g><path d='m100,0l-100,0c50,0 50,100 100,100' stroke-width='1.5' stroke='black' fill='gray' /></g></svg>");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="curve-right-left-top" style="width: 30px"></td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="curve-right-left-bottom" style="width: 30px"></td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="curve-left-right-top" style="width: 30px"></td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="curve-left-right-bottom" style="width: 30px"></td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Instead of using 4 mirrored SVGs you can of course also apply CSS transformations to only one SVG via `transform: scaleX(-1);` etc.

Comment: Will it work on html table rows Sir? How will I apply it dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I added a simple example table. What do you mean with "apply it dynamically"? This depends entirely on how you create your tables.

Comment: Because the number of rows in tables file 1 and file 2 are dynamic so the curve will depend upon the height of the row. Anyway I will try it Sir. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Sir how will I reverse the curve?

Comment: I added examples for mirrored curves.